# CheckBox & Database Update

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a form as below which allows user to select different collar types. Each checkbox has a collar id which will be submitted when the form is submitted.

[image: collar types]

Assume that user selected 1st three collars. It would look like this.

[image: collar types]

Then what I do is add these three collar to my collars table using an insert statement. After that If user wants, he can uncheck the collar types or add new.

Assume that user unchecked the 2nd type as below.

[image: collar types]

Now the particular row which refer to the 2nd collar type must be deleted from the table. Below images shows the table structure.

[image]

Now my problem is When the form is submitted if user has made any changes(checked new checkbox or unchecked any) How can I Insert or delete a row? Do I have to write SELECT statement for each checkbox and see whether that collar id exists?

Help me out with the logic because I'm able to build the code myself according to a given logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 solutions:

1. You have to SELECT all ids from your table and verify if the checkboxes are selected or not:

   ```
   $array = array();
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT collor_id FROM my_table WHERE product_id='x'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       array_push($array, $row['collor_id']);
   }

   if(count($_POST['my_collors']) > 0) {
       foreach($_POST['my_collors'] as $value) {
           if(!in_array($value, $array)) {
                // insert it into db
                // unset the array value for this collor id
           } else {
            // unset the array value for this collor id
           }
       }
   }

   // foreach remained array value delete them from the db
   ```
2. You can DELETE * the entries from the table for the selected product and then INSERT the new values

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to write SELECT statement for each checkbox and see whether that collar id exists?

The database can tell you if that ID exists or not, so that does the database.

However, you need to run two queries, one for deletion(s) and one for the insert(s).

Comment: yes I know that I have to write two queries. What I want to know is the logic. How to accomplish depending on the situation. How can I know whether user has check anything new or unchecked any?

Comment: Create the list of IDs to set. Use them on the delete query with `NOT IN()`. Use them in the insert query with `IN()`. Job done. First run the delete query, then the insert query I would say but that is technically not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I Think if you can save the id or product_id for the particular user than delete its earlier entry and create a new row of that user using that ID.
Or Update that row using the id.